# How to put Logo & navigation in one line

Tags: css, navigation, css-float

I have a css and HTML code which has two sections in the header: one for Logo and other one for navigation. I wanted to put both in the same line so that it saves some space and looks much better. Can someone guide me on how I can do that?

http://css.pastebin.com/AdGMQum5

Comment: Unfortunately, the code snippet has been deleted, making this question useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Set width for your logo for example 100px;
2. `Float:left;` logo
3. Remove `width:100%;` and `float:left;` from `#nav`
4. Add `overflow:hidden;` for `#nav`
5. add `clear:left;` for `#content`

*Live example:* http://jsbin.com/eyozo

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method is simply to use a `background-image` on the `h1` element:

```
h1 {
    padding-left: 200px; /* width of the image plus a 'buffer' between image and text */
    height: 150px; /* vertical height of the image */
    line-height: 150px; /* to vertically-align the image with the text */
    background: #fff url(path/to/image.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: A logo is semantic content, don't change the HTML when you change the style.

Comment: @zzzzBov, that's perhaps a difference of opinion. For me a business logo/branding semantically **means** the business name; therefore, for me, I prefer to have the logo as a background to that name. But each to their own.

Comment: A logo is a very specific design that may or may not include the business name. Logotypes with the business name include not only the textual representation of the name but the sizing and typeface. Using it as a background to HTML content may mask the desired appearance.

Comment: It **may**, it **may** not; that's the whole point, that it *may*. It's a personal, stylistic choice. I offered one option (with which I obviously agree), but I don't advocate that as necessarily the *best* (and certainly not the *only*) solution. But in the absence of any directive from @chirag, the OP, I don't think my solution was any *less* valid than any other.

Comment: you misunderstand me when I say it may or may not include the name of the business. When a logo is being displayed, it must appear **the same** using the same font, spacing, and alignment, otherwise it **is not** the same logo. You cannot guarantee the typeface using text in HTML, but you can guarantee the display of an image (all or none). It most definitely **is not** a stylistic choice of the person programming the HTML, it **is** a stylistic choice of the person *designing the logo*. To suggest otherwise not a difference of opinion, rather a blatant disregard of logotype.